# GameCenter reporting achievements Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I'm getting a bit frustrated. I'm implementing achievements using GameCenter and Swift 3

However I get the error.

no bundle for bundleID: (null)

I've been following tutorials such as those from raywenderlich.com but can't find any for Swift 3 with achievements (I have leaderboards working) so don't know if my code is incorrect, or how I can just return the bundle IDs programatically to confirm the achievement ID.

To try to get this working in ViewDidLoad I coded the following, and my ViewController is a GKGameCenterControllerDelegate

```
    var achievements = [GKAchievement]()
    let fullAchievement = GKAchievement(
             identifier: "ReversedIDforMyApp.FullMarks")
    achievements.append(fullAchievement)
    GameKitHelper.sharedInstance.reportAchievements(achievements: achievements)
```

I created a helper to report the achievement

```
func reportAchievements(achievements: [GKAchievement],
                        errorHandler: ((NSError?)->Void)? = nil) {
    guard gameCenterEnabled else {
        return
    }
    GKAchievement.report(achievements,
                                     withCompletionHandler: errorHandler as? (Error?) -> Void)
}
}
```

I can't work out why the error message would be displayed...

Comment: I get the same error with my app. From what I found out its an error with xCode so just ignore it. Are your achievements working? Do achievements show when you go to the game centre? Is this an update to your app? If its an update check that your iTunes connect version you have added the achievements to is the same as the version number in Xcode. Say the live version is 1.0 so new version is 1.1, the version needs to be 1.1 in Xcode when running the app else achievements won't show.

Comment: It's a new App. The achievement shows in game centre, but I could not get it to work.

Comment: I would recommend using [link](https://github.com/jackcook/GCHelper). Its a good library and very easy to use. You can implement the game centre using a couple of functions. Just drop the GCHelper.swift file into your project and your good to go. You shouldn't have any problems with it.

Comment: Which is great, and appreciated but I'm only trying to get it to work as a learning experience - need to know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that it can take a long time for Apple to set up Game Center achievements, and in the end the code was Ok. Go figure.

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong but try and set the percent and the banner completion on your GKAchievement object.

```
var achievements = [GKAchievement]()
let fullAchievement = GKAchievement(identifier:"ReversedIDforMyApp.FullMarks")
fullAchievement.percentComplete = 100  //Set this
fullAchievement.showsCompletionBanner = true //Set this
achievements.append(fullAchievement)
GameKitHelper.sharedInstance.reportAchievements(achievements: achievements)

func reportAchievements(achievements: [GKAchievement]) {
    guard gameCenterEnabled else {
        return
    }
    GKAchievement.report([achievements]) { (error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error in reporting achievements: \(error)")
            return
        }
    } 
}
```